# Wordpress downloaded images resizes itself

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wordpress and woocommerce. I have one problem, i have created a system with downloads steam market items (names and pictures) and then creates products. But I have one problem, downloaded images that are used for product are automaticly resized to a different resolutions : 150x113 300x225 300x300 425x280 and original one. So it takes 5x space, which is a problem for me. How do i disable or fix that resizing problem. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this article [here by WP Mayor](http://www.wpmayor.com/remove-image-sizes-in-wordpress/). Basically you remove the code that produces them.

```
function wpmayor_filter_image_sizes( $sizes) {

    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['large']);
    unset( $sizes['wysija-newsletters-max']);

return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'wpmayor_filter_image_sizes');

function wpmayor_custom_image_sizes($sizes) {
$myimgsizes = array(
  "image-in-post" => __( "Image in Post" ),
  "full" => __( "Original size" )
);
return $myimgsizes;
}
add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'wpmayor_custom_image_sizes');
```

place this in your functions.php file

UPDATE:
Also look [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-prevent-wordpress-from-generating-image-sizes/) - Seems you just go to the media page, and set the other sizes to 0
[image]

Comment: Links are temporary, if you link something write a little bit more detailed tutorial, so OP and the users after him won't find a dead-end with a broken link in the future :)

Comment: In woocommerce there is also something similar like media settings… :)

Comment: Thanks @asurbernardo, didn't know links were temp

Comment: @James No no, stackoverflow do not erase them or anything like that, what I meant is that maybe the owner of that web may take it down for any reason, and your answer will be uncomplete, it's perfect if you say where the information comes from (it's recommended) but try to make your answer self sufficient just in case... ;)

Comment: @asurbernardo - ahh okay, yes thank you. I agree and will keep in mind. :)

Answer (score 2):

By default, WordPress generates three sizes of each image that you upload. Themes and plugins can generate additional images sizes aswell.

**First thing you should keep in mind is that the default image sizes are not harmful for your website**.

If you already know this but you want to proceed anyway (or your space is really limited), you will need to do some steps to make Wordpress just keep the original image:

1. First you need to understand how many copies of an uploaded image
   are generated by WordPress. You can check that using FTP client and
   accesing `/wp-content/uploads/` directory.
2. You can stop WordPress from generating default image sizes by
   visiting Settings » Media in WordPress admin area.  There you will
   see default image sizes predefined by WordPress. You need to set
   these sizes to 0 which will prevent WordPress from generating
   default image sizes when you upload a new image.
3. Finally your theme might be generating other thumbnails (check it in
   step 1), if this is the case look into your theme’s
   `functions.php` file. Simply look for the code line containing:

   ```
   add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true );
   ```

   and

   ```
   set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );
   ```

> Note: WordPress uses the thumbnail image size for galleries and theme pages so they might break after you prevent their generation.

If you need further information I suggest you to check the [original source](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-prevent-wordpress-from-generating-image-sizes/) of this post.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

**MAKING YOUR IMAGES LIGHTER (JPEG COMPRESSION HOOK).**

It don't take "5x space" but between x1.5 and x3 max, because other sizes are lighter, depending of their dimension and number of different sizes.

But you can make your images even much more lighter with this native hook:

```
add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', create_function( '', 'return 80;' ) );
```

You can tune the compression value replacing `80` by a number from `0` to `100`. This hook doesn't compress your original image, but only all the others. If you want to use it you will need to paste it in the function.php file of your active child theme or theme.

**IMAGES SETTINGS IN WOOCOMMERCE:**

[image]

They are located in left menu `Woocommerce > Settings > Products > Display`. You can change all values to 0 (similar to Wordpress Media settings).

As the others answers suggested, you can unset somme of them programatically. Is better to keep thumbnails, because they are used to display images in the media library.

Comment: Some hosts do file counts, and penalize you over say 100k, so that could pose a problem resizing so many. Just a thought

Comment: I only have that experience with my company's hosting provider. My own I do not. I would offer the same advice to find new hosting. The hosting my company uses is Hostgator just fyi

Comment: @James I have mine to and a lot of different from my clients… Never had that kind of behavior from hosters

Comment: I think it's because I work for a non-profit, and the hosting is partly 'in-kind' - so we have limits because of that reason